# Working with a QString encoding

Tags: python, encoding

Is there a Python library which can detect (and perhaps decode) encoding of the string?

I found [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) but it gives me an error, using:

```
chardet.detect(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
got: = chardet.detect(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
File .... u.feed(aBuf) File .... 
if self._highBitDetector.search(aBuf):

TypeError: buffer size mismatch
```

Also:

```
print type(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
# <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>
```

Comment: You need to explain why chardet isn't what you want - it's exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, maybe itsn't right, that chardet isn't that what i need. I have an error during this lib using:
chardet.detect(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
got:
    = chardet.detect(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
  File ....
    u.feed(aBuf)
  File ....
    if self._highBitDetector.search(aBuf):
TypeError: buffer size mismatch

Comment: You're getting errors in all the code you've posted that involves self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText() - are you sure that isn't already giving you a Unicode string?  Or something that isn't a string at all?  What does print type(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText()) give?

Comment: <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>
I'm using Qt and Python (PyQt).

Comment: Gotcha - You need to convert your QString to a Python string before passing it to chardet.  See my new answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert your `QString` to a Python string before passing it to `chardet`.  Change this:

```
chardet.detect(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
```

to this:

```
chardet.detect(str(self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is another option.

http://cthedot.de/encutils/

> A collection of helper functions to detect encodings of text files (like HTML, XHTML, XML, CSS, etc.) retrieved via HTTP, file or string.

Comment: How can i get encoding info of the string?
encutils.getEncodingInfo(text=self.ui.TextFrom.toPlainText())
Calls an error: AttributeError: find in _getTextType.